# AS3 - Building a Dynamic Menu based on External Images

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I have a fun addition to a project that could be a great feature for many other people as well.  I have a remote directory with a number of images that frequently change in content and quantity.

I am trying to make a text dropdown menu of movieclip buttons with the names of the images, so each image can be loaded and viewed individually.  But I want to populate the menu dynamically based on the number of images in the folder and the buttons labeled based either on the filenames or from a separate text file with the names.

------- So I know how to build a text menu through scripting, but I don't know how to get the information of --1) the number of images or --2) the names.  Can this be done through action script??  In case this sounds too easy, the number of images is usually around 50, so it is a scrolling menu.  So I guess I also somehow need to --3) define the length of the scrolling menu movieclip, based on the number of buttons it dynamically created. =-)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless it's an AIR application you can't make an ActionScript file read contents of a directory by itself (or inspect file system).

Your best option in this scenario is to load a server-side script like PHP that will open a folder and output its contents in XML format. Then your ActionScript file will process this XML and create necessary visual data.

This way you will know that the file data/listing is always up-to-date and foolproof.

Comment: That's what I was guessing/fearing would be the answer... Time to go learn some PHP!

Comment: Do not fear! :) The functions you will need to use in that script are `opendir()` to open a directory (folder), `readdir()` to read the contents of it and many `echo`s to output all that info as XML data. Don't forget to use `header("Content-type: text/xml");` before outputting anything if you want this to be a proper xml by mime type as well.

Comment: Many thanks for steering me in the right direction!  What a prompt and concise response!!  I will add the PHP code as an answer when it's done for anyone else who may stumble upon this with the same questions.

Comment: No problem. I forgot one function. It's a good practice to check if a file `file_exists()` or folder `is_dir()` exists when you're looking for a particular item. You can also check if that file/folder is readable but I don't think you will need that at this point.